# Schema based multi-tenancy with hibernate on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm implementing a multi-tenancy capable application based on Java 8, Spring Boot 2 and JPA/Hibernate 5

There are different approaches to this, I chose the schema based approach. The [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) also write about support for this.

I also looked at some [tutorials](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy)

But it seems like everyone on the net uses native SQL to switch schema. Not only do I have to support multiple DBMS - but I could provide different implementations - but it seems like **MS SQL Server does not support setting a schema** for the duration of a connection only.

There is a `setSchema(String)` method on the JDBC Connection object, but [MS does not support it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/jdbc-4-1-compliance-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=ssdt-18vs2017) (also verified by looking at their source on Github). Not only that, but I can't find a way using T-SQL either.

Is there another way to set the connection schema in my ConnectionProvider, or do I have to switch to a completely different approach (e.g., discriminator column based)?

FYI, the schemas have to be dynamic, since tenants can be created via the UI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMHO, the best multi-tenant strategy for your application requirements, would have been COLUMN DISCRIMINATOR strategy ... But it's still under development and not available with the last Hibernate 5.3.2 release.

> FYI, the schemas have to be dynamic, since tenants can be created via the UI.

Using schema strategy with this high portable requirements is very hard to implement for some reasons:

- Schema concepts are very different across database vendors
- Hibernate multi-tenant solution is yet very light

I suggest, you lower your portable requirements and choose only database vendors giving you the tools for effective multi-tenant schema strategy.

Comment: We switched to a manually implemented discriminator column based approach

Comment: @Benjamin Maurer: That's the best choice with current Hibernate 5.3 release. You still have possibility in future release, to let the persistence take the lead. Check how EclipseLink column discriminator. solution is made, to make good provision. By the way, using single column discriminator, it will be easy to switch to the Persistence vendor solution. The switch 2-key factors  being :  1. Vendor solution efficiency in data query/update.  2. Your code cleanup and more business oriented.